# GestureOverlayView: changing gesture color while swiping

Tags: java, android, user-interface, colors, gesture

I have only a simple `MyGestureOverlayView extends GestureOverlayView` in my layout; I want that when the user swipes and the GestureOverlayView recognizes the gesture, it doesn't change color. I want that the color will change only when I call `overlay.setGestureColor(int color)`, but in fact this method changes the color that will have the next gesture when recognized by the super class, not while the user is swiping.
So my question is: how can I change the color of the gesture while the user is performing the gesture?

```
public class MyGestureOverlayView extends GestureOverlayView implements 
                               GestureOverlayView.OnGesturePerformedListener, 
                               GestureOverlayView.OnGestureListener {

private static final String TAG = MyGestureOverlayView.class.getName();

private GiocoActivity mContext;

private boolean mRecognized;

private GestureLibrary gestures;

public MyGestureOverlayView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    if (context instanceof GiocoActivity)

        mContext = (GiocoActivity) context;

    gestures = GestureLibraries.fromRawResource(mContext, R.raw.gesture);

    if (!gestures.load())
        mContext.finish();

    addOnGesturePerformedListener(this);
    addOnGestureListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView overlay, Gesture gesture) {
    ArrayList<Prediction> predictions = gestures.recognize(gesture);
    Log.d(TAG, "Gesture riconosciuta!");
    // Sorry for my English :)

    if (predictions.size() > 0 && predictions.get(0).score > 3.0) {

        overlay.setGestureColor(Color.GREEN);
        // The color doesn't change here, but it will change in the next gesture

        String action = predictions.get(0).name;

        mRecognized = true;

        Toast.makeText(mContext, action, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else {
        overlay.setGestureColor(Color.RED);
        // The color doesn't change here, but it will change in the next gesture
        mRecognized = false;
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "Fine riconoscimento Gesture; esito: "+ mRecognized);
}

@Override
public void onGestureStarted(GestureOverlayView overlay, MotionEvent event) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Gesture iniziata!");

}

@Override
public void onGesture(GestureOverlayView overlay, MotionEvent event) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Gesture in corso!");
    if (mRecognized)  // Always false for the first gesture
        overlay.setGestureColor(Color.GREEN); // Same as before
    else
        overlay.setGestureColor(Color.RED);  // Same as before
}

@Override
public void onGestureEnded(GestureOverlayView overlay, MotionEvent event) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Gesture finita!");

}

@Override
public void onGestureCancelled(GestureOverlayView overlay, MotionEvent event) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Gesture cancellata!");

}
}
```

Besides, the callback method `onGesturePerformed` is called after `onGestureEnded`, so the boolean mRecognized in `onGesture()` is always false whem I perform a gesture for the first time and when it'll be recognized from the super class it'll be displayed red in any case (both recognized or not by my `onGesturePerformedListener`).
Sorry if I was complicate, this is my first question, and I found only one question similar to this, but it has no answers.
Thanks for your time.